# Is there a way to get the user's time zone offset based on the WCF request?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF operation (let's call it **GetItems**), and the response is a list of items with a *TimeTaken* property of data type DateTime. The *TimeTaken* for every item is stored in UTC in our database. What I am attempting to do is to convert the *TimeTaken* from UTC to the requestor's time zone.

Does the request made to the WCF contain the requestor's time zone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the service need to know the client's timezone? If this is only being done so that the UTC time can be converted for local display, I'd say let the client handle the conversion.

Comment: What's the client? Unless you're *telling* the client to specify the time zone (e.g. as another parameter) then no, it won't include the time zone.

Comment: @DanJ I guess the client can handle the conversion. The service was using a third party tool that determines the timezone based on a user's IP address. That REST call sometimes took 5 seconds to give back results, that's why I was hoping to move away from that.

Comment: For the most part, I'd consider it good separation of concerns to have the service emit dates in UTC and let the clients worry about converting them if needed. The client only needs to pass its timezone if the server has to do something the client shouldn't know about: E.g. If you're generating a timestamp at the client that the service must normalize into UTC for persistence.